# How do I remove punctuation from an item in a list and save it as a separate item in the list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist, compression

I am trying to compress items from one list to another list and I need to be able to save punctuation as separate items in the list because if I don't, "you" and "you;" are saved as separate items in the list.

For example the original list is,

`['Ask', 'not', 'what', 'your', 'country', 'can', 'do', 'for', 'you;', 'ask', 'what', 'you', 'can', 'do', 'for', 'your', 'country!', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'quote', 'from', 'JFK', 'who', 'is', 'a', 'former', 'American', 'President.']`

and the compressed list is currently,

`['Ask', 'not', 'what', 'your', 'country', 'can', 'do', 'for', 'you;', 'ask', 'you', 'country!', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'quote', 'from', 'JFK', 'who', 'former', 'American', 'President.']`

but I want it to have punctuation as separate  items in the list.

My intended output is,

`['Ask', 'not', 'what', 'your', 'country', 'can', 'do', 'for', 'you', ';', 'ask', '!', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'quote', 'from', 'JFK', 'who', 'former', 'American', 'President', '.']`

Comment: Please give some examples.

Comment: What's ur expected output?

Comment: u mean `[re.sub(r'[:?.!]', '', s) for s in lst]`

Comment: I'm sorry I am not sure what to do with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement with `regex`.

```
import re
a = ['Ask', 'not', 'what', 'your', 'country', 'can', 'do', 'for', 'you;', 'ask', 'what', 'you', 'can', 'do', 'for', 'your', 'country!', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'quote', 'from', 'JFK', 'who', 'is', 'a', 'former', 'American', 'President.']
result = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]",' '.join(a))
```

**Output**

```
['Ask', 'not', 'what', 'your', 'country', 'can', 'do', 'for', 'you', ';', 'ask', 'what', 'you', 'can', 'do', 'for', 'your', 'country', '!', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'quote', 'from', 'JFK', 'who', 'is', 'a', 'former', 'American', 'President', '.']
```

Here is a demo to understand more about [regex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JMUsMsb6jFI1e5l7).

Comment: looks good but I still can't get it to work. Maybe because I don't know where to put it.

Comment: Your input is `a` right (specified in my answer). Where you exactly put this peace of code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to separete the non alphabetic characters and also remove duplicates. hope it helps.

```
def separate(mylist):
    newlist = [] 
    test = ''
    a = ''
    for e in mylist:
        for c in e:   
            if not c.isalpha():
                a = c
            else:
                test = test + c
        if a != '':
            newlist = newlist + [test] + [a]
        else:
            newlist = newlist + [test]
        test = ''
        a = ''
    noduplicates = []
    for i in newlist:
        if i not in noduplicates:
            noduplicates = noduplicates + [i]
    return noduplicates
```

I`m sure someone else can do better couse this is a bit messy but at least works.

Comment: He don't want to remove the alphabetic character. He just want to separate the punctuation from the word and make into separate list.

Comment: Don't really want to remove them, I want to save them as a separate item in the list

Comment: oh ok give me a sec then